# Does Client have to know Impl of an Object returned by RMI Server?

Tags: java, client, rmi

I just wondered if the Client has to know actual Implementations of the objects on the server. I thought the Client only has to know the interfaces of the objects on the server.

Example (on the server side):

```
public class AccountImpl implements Account {
    //lots of Code
}

public class AccountManagerImpl implements AccountManager {
    public Account login() {
        return new AccountImpl();
    }
}
```

on the client side:

```
AccountManager accMan = (AccountManager) registry.lookup("accMan");

Account myAccount = accMan.login();
```

So the client has the interface Account. Does he need to know the implementation of the class AccountImpl, too? Since every User should get his own Account I don't think I can export and bind them to the registry... How is this usually done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No. The client only uses the remote interface. The classes that need to be deployed to the client include only the remote interface itself and any classes it depends on and so on recursively until closure. If you're generating pre-1.5 stubs, they also need to be deployed, or else made available via the RMI codebase feature.

You don't need to bind Account to the registry. What you've posted here already works.

Comment: I get following Error in the client:
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return;
To me this sounds like the client needs AccountImpl. How can I fix this?

Comment: Got it working now. AccountImpl implements Account, Serializable

Comment: That's probably not what you want. You almost certainly want Account to be a remote object. Otherwise any changes the client does to it will be lost, and he client won't see concurrent changes to it that happen at the server.

Comment: I see. so I made Account extends Remote. Do I need AccountImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject, too?

Comment: Yes, or else export it yourself when you construct it.